# does kinect for windows work on turtlebot?

Tags: kinect, openni, turtlebot, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to install kinect for windows ([kinect4windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/)) on the turtlebot (and not xbox kinect)[xboxkinect](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/KINECT)

I have been eating out my brains for last 2 days trying the openni driver to work, and still the device is not detected. The kinect is blinking and getting power from the turtlebot sensor board. But after multiple trial I am unable to get it work.

Does anyone has experience of getting it worked on turtlebot? Please reply , else I will have to get a Xbox kinect as a last resort.

PS- Turtlebot page should mention this point to new users.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46173/does-kinect-for-windows-work-on-turtlebot?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe it does.  Check out my answer to your other question.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0